# find correct text height in for a uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, sizewithfont

I have a table displaying different texts, therefore I need to adjust my cell height accordingly. I use the delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
// I ask for my content string and then I want to adjust the cell accordingly:
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(defaultCell.textLabel.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
GSize neededSize = [contentString sizeWithFont:defaultCell.textLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:defaultCell.textLabel.lineBreakMode];
CGFloat cellHeight = neededSize.height +15;
return cellHeight;
```

The default cell is my protoype cell of the storyboard. I initialise it in the viewDidAppear delegate method so I can access easily my protoype uitableviewcell, in this way I only have to change something like the font in my storyboard.

The Problem I have is that the function sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode: does not give me accurate answers. If there are only a few very short words in the next line it will give a result one line too low.

Does anybode have an idea why that is and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be differences in the cell width when you load the view, and when it's rendered.  My shot-in-the-dark would be that the cell frame you think you're working with, isn't the same cell frame that's being rendered.

Comment: So what would be a better way to handle this? I switched to using the default cell because when the delegate method for the cell height is called, the other cells aren't initialised yet.

Comment: If you override `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath`and print the frame of cell.textLabel, on an iPhone screen (basic cell), the frame is `(10 0; 300 44)`, on an iPad screen the left and right margins remain 10 pixels each; so I would hard-code the -20px from the  `defaultCell.textLabel.frame.size.width`, but leave a comment to indicate what that 20px actually represents and why it's being removed.